# program self loops in shell script, but want script to control looping

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sh

I have a shell script (plotter.sh) that runs a program that currently loops infinitely on it's own (see below). The problem is when I want to tweak the program's options/syntax I typically wait until a loop is complete, stop the script, make my tweaks to the program's options and start the script again. The program does have an option to run once. With that said, how do I set it up so the shell script controls the looping and I can make changes to the program's options on the fly, the program automatically runs with the new changes on the subsequent loop - all without having to stop anything?

```
#!/bin/bash

#VARIABLES
poolcontactaddress=gjghkjhj
farmerpublickey=gjhgjhgjhgjh
farmid=${farmerpublickey: -6}
timestamp=$(date +'%Y%m%d-%H%M%S')
loopid=$(uuid)
#runid=$(uuid)


~/chia/chia-plotter/build/chia_plot -c $poolcontactaddress -f $farmerpublickey -t /mnt/u2-0052/ -2 /mnt/ramdisk/ -n -1 -r 48 -u 128 2>&1 | tee ~/chia/logs/plotter-$farmid-$loopid-$timestamp.log;
```

Comment: So if you have a loop in the script how do you tell the script the options in a way that they can be changed at any time without stopping the script?  Use environment variables - you can change them externally at any time.

Comment: A common way to do this in daemon programs is to send a signal to the program. The signal handler rereads the daemon's configuration file. You can use `trap` in a shell script to do similarly.

Comment: @JerryJeremiah Really? `export v=1; while sleep 3; do echo "$v"; done & sleep 4; v=2; sleep 4; kill %`